# mix deps.get fails (dependency issue)

Tags: postgresql, elixir, phoenix-framework, elixir-mix

i'm quite new to elixir and phoenix (and ubuntu) and have been battling to get myself up and running with web development.
upon creating a new phoenix application using

```
mix phoenix.new webapp
```

i get the following errors from terminal

```
Fetch and install dependencies? [Yn] y
* running mix deps.get
* error command failed to execute, please run the following command again after installation: "mix deps.get"
* running npm install && node node_modules/brunch/bin/brunch build
* error command failed to execute, please run the following command again after installation: "npm install && node node_modules/brunch/bin/brunch build"
```

and when running `mix deps.get`

the resultant error message is

```
** (Mix) No package with name phoenix_ecto (from: mix.exs) in registry
```

I'm still quite new when it comes to using this platform, so i'm not entirely sure how to pull/get/place/download the `phoenix_ecto` package in the registry.
From what i understand this is all handled by hex package manager.

I did manage to get phoenix up and running a few days ago, and managed to play around a little bit with developing small test applications. 
but it seems somewhere in my reckless terminal sudoing i managed to break something somewhere.

some extra information

```
Elixir 1.3.4
Mix 1.3.4
npm 3.5.2
node v4.2.6
Phoenix v1.2.1
```

If any other information is required i will happily provide!

Comment: That's an odd error.  Yes phoenix_ecto should be handled by hex.  If I were you I'd try adding the dependency directly to your mix file if it's not already there. Like so: {:phoenix_ecto, "~> 3.1.0-rc.0"}

Comment: i checked my mix.exs file and the dependency was already as {:phoenix_ecto, "~> 3.0"}

Answer (score 9):

I managed to fix the error by unlocking the dependencies and updating them.
the commands are below.

```
mix deps.unlock --all
mix deps.update --all
```

Now the projects are created and build no problem.
Hope this helps someone.

Edit 1:

If the above does not work, there is the possibility that your hex install has been corrupted. This was my case about a week after the original post. Can be fixed by removing hex and reinstalling.

```
rm -rf ~/.mix/archives/hex-0.15.0
mix local.hex
```

your hex version may be different from mine.

```
hex-0.xx.x
```

Comment: I was just about to suggest insuring that your dependencies were all unlocked.  Glad you found it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

This may appear in several cases. First check you `mix.exs` deps section. Ensure `phoenix_ecto` placed with right version and opts. Further you need check `phoenix_ecto` from local just clone repo and set `{:phoenix_ecto, path: "..."}`in you project. Try to compile local. If it compiles local and not compiles in deps check phoenix_ecto mix.exs file and `defp package` method and ensure that return list with mix.exs `[_, .., file: ~w{mix.exs}, _]`.

In common this problem relate to mix.exs.